# Find and replace multiple file in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to implement a find and replace for all files in a folder using a vbs script, here is what I have so far

```
Dim fso,folder,files,oldFileContents,newFileContents,FIND,REPLACE

FIND = "textToBeReplaced"
REPLACE = "localhost"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set folder = fso.GetFolder("HTML")
Set files = folder.Files

For each item In files
    oldFileContents = GetFile(item.Path)
    newFileContents = replace(oldFileContents,FIND,REPLACE,1,-1,1)
    WriteFile FileName,newFileContents
Next
```

but when I try to run it I get and error, "Type Mismatch: 'GetFile'", what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out the `fso.` on

```
oldFileContents = fso.GetFile(item.Path)
```

and

```
fso.WriteFile FileName,newFileContents
```

EDIT:  as per discussion below, please note this answer was only meant to show where your error was occurring.  It was assumed that your intent was to develop your code further once your got past this error, which if so, I’m sure you’ve already seen Ekkehard has provided some very helpful guidance on his answer.

Comment: -1 - .GetFile() returns a File object, not the file's content

Comment: @ekkehard I was simply showing why the `GetFile` was falling.  Which Is all that was asked.  What it get used for after that is nothing to do with me

Comment: For "What it get used for after that is nothing to do with me" and for forgetting the Set when attempting to show the usage of .GetFile() you deserve another downvote.

Comment: I agree that you have given a well written answer in full, and for that you do deserve +1.  But I will point out this sites FAQ sates; “Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful...”, admittedly it does go on to say that your type of answer is “better”, but giving an answer which is “better” does not mean “This answer is not useful” and deserves a downvote

Comment: I still believe your answer does not point in the right direction at all, but I'm willing to take back the downvote if you edit it (perhaps showing the correct usage of .GetFile() or correcting the .Write**File**).

Comment: I think I see your point now; that I should have at least specified that my answer was only directing Eamonn as to why he was getting this error, and for that perhaps my answer should keep the downvote :(.  So I will apply an edit to this affect.  Thanks for actually explaining your reasons for the downvote

Comment: Answer was confusing / not helpful to me. The question title led me here from a Google search on how to best to accomplish string replacements in files. This answer would just lead me down the rabbit hole...

Answer (score 3):

The problem should be solved with code like:

```
' Constants Mr Gates forgot (but cf. vbTextCompare)
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2
' Configuration constants  
  Const csFind     = "pdf"
  Const csRepl     = "puf"
' Dim & init for vars needed on *this* level   
  Dim oFS   : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sTDir : sTDir   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\test")
  Dim oFile
  For Each oFile In oFS.GetFolder(sTDir).Files
      WScript.Echo "looking at", oFile.Name
      ' Dim & init for vars needed on *this* level   
      Dim sContent : sContent = goFS.GetFile(oFile.Path)
      ' For Skytunnels and other air-coders
      WScript.Echo "content is not", sContent
      ' you got oFile, so use it; no need for .GetFile()
      sContent = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading).ReadAll()
      WScript.Echo "qed! content is", sContent
      ' Replace(expression, find, replacewith[, start[, count[, compare]]])
      ' don't use magic numbers; vbTextCompare is even pre-defined
      sContent = Replace(sContent, csFind, csRepl, 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
      WScript.Echo "new content", sContent
      oFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting).Write sContent
      sContent = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading).ReadAll()
      WScript.Echo "new content straight from file", sContent
      WScript.Echo "------------------"
  Next
```

output:

```
...
------------------
looking at 0000000000012345.20120302.pdf
content is not E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\9117277\data\test\0000000000012345.20120302.pdf
qed! content is This is the content of 0000000000012345.20120302.pdf

new content This is the content of 0000000000012345.20120302.puf

new content straight from file This is the content of 0000000000012345.20120302.puf
```

Important points:

1. Don't use a Dim-all-vars-ever-used-line at the top of your script
2. Avoid creation of unnecessary vars (folder, files, *contents), use
   the vars you have properly (item==oFile)
3. .GetFile() returns a File object, not the file's content